# Windows vista/7/8 "automatically" installed drivers questions

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-vista, usb, drivers

Where do the automatically installed drivers get installed in windows? Where do they get installed from (I can install them without the internet). Why do they need to be installed if they already reside on the OS, cant they just be "preinstalled"? How can I remove one of these "drivers"? And lastly, do other operating systems do this? (I find it quite surprising that windows would need to install a "driver" for my CPU even...I got this message before once when I changed cpus) 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Everything needs a "driver". Even the system clock.  Otherwise, how does the OS talk to it??

Comment: OS X and Linux do not automatically install drivers for devices.  This is a unique feature of Windows.  Its worth pointing out that OS X already has the drivers installed for devices like a `USB Input` Device installed

Answer (score 1):

Drivers are how the OS and the hardware talk to each other.  Therefore, every single device needs a driver.  Microsoft has a built in driver library that ships with each version of their OS.  These drivers include the most commonly used drivers and drivers, which makes life more convenient for everyone.  They arent preinstalled or part of the OS, they are just there in case they are needed.  And yes, most OSs, do this.  It makes installing OSs much easier than it used to be.